# How to set value of outer variable in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am kind of a beginner to javascript. This is a javascript problem, but for the record, this is a program done in `node.js` using `hapi` and `mongoose`. Tables is a model in `mongoose`.

My problem is that I want to set the response to a value so I can send it later:

```
handler: function (request, reply) {
    var response;
    Tables.find(function find(err, mesas) {
        if (err) 
            response = reply({ error: err});
        else 
            response = reply({mesas : mesas}).hold;
        });
    }
    response.send();
}
```

For some reason, server returns "undefined does not have method 'send'", and I guess that is because it is referenced inside an anonymous function. This brings a couples of thoughts to me:

1) Am I writing this in a non javascript idiomatic way?
2) What is the best approach to to makes this work?

**EDIT:**
The response.send() call was actually outside of the `Tables.find(...)`.

Comment: Again the everyday async question... You can't return inside a continuation. Use promises, or do the logic inside the callback.

Comment: I apologize if I asked a duplicate, please link to it if I did.

Comment: response.send(), will be executed before the Table.find callback. You have to send the response back to the client within the Table.find callback.

Comment: No need to apologize, it's a common duplicate yes, but it's a common misunderstanding as well.

Comment: @RobertMoskal I'm sorry, I edited it, response.send() is called outside.

Comment: @elclanrs Oh, thanks, that done()/fail() call at the end is nice indeed.

Comment: Keep in mind that syntax is probably library dependent. Not sure about mongoose, but it is probable that it returns a promise.